# How can you tell whether a website is using the LAMP or MEAN Stack when looking at the script in the developer panel?

Tags: mean-stack, lamp, developer-tools

I'm starting to learn the basics of LAMP and MEAN. I'd like to dive in by learning LAMP first.

There's a website that I like to replicate, but I don't know whether it's using LAMP or MEAN.

How can I tell the difference by taking a cursory look within the developer panel in the Chrome browser?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the good framework is using REST or LESS or something that does not include a file extension in the URL (.php, .html etc)

you can use guess.scritch.org/ or... a new post with the chrome dev tool method will be posted in a minute.

Comment: I was just thinking, You decided you would like LAMP to be the first framework to learn so why don't you get a lamp tutorial and deploy it as a 1st time test, then implement a template like the one you are trying to clone ? e.g. get a responsive html template or copy the html from one that isn't going to be total plagiarism